# Possible user-dependent ODBC data source?

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc

Is it possible to define many ODBC data sources with the same name, each of which is assigned to different user (login) of Windows Server 2012? The problem is an application uses such a source to connecto to SQL Server. As a result, every user of that app connects to the same SQL Server instance and uses the same database, which is undesirable. I'd like the app to use ODBC data source with the same name to connect to different SQL Server instance, depending on the user that has logged in to the system. In fact, it would then work in a sense like a virtual data source.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: you should be able to do this by defining DSNs in ODBC Administrator in the "User DSN" tab rather than the "System DSN" one. I've never done the equivalent programmatically. Note that you would need to ensure everyone operating in support was familiar with this, as now problem reports for a given DSN do not resolve to a single database instance.

Comment: @mc110 I'll see if I can apply your solution in our VPS as soon as possible. If so - I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should be able to do this manually by defining DSNs in ODBC Administrator in the "User DSN" tab rather than the "System DSN" one.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213772 has a section explaining the difference between System and User DSNs:

> User DSN
>
> The User DSN is a data source that is user-specific. A User
>   DSN is stored locally but is available only to the user who creates
>   it. User DSNs are not used by Microsoft Query. If you use Microsoft
>   Jet, ODBC, or Structured Query Language (SQL) commands and bypass
>   Microsoft Query, User DSNs are required.
>
> User DSNs are stored in the
>   Windows registry under the following key:
>
> ```
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Odbc\Odbc.ini\Odbc Data sources
> ```
>
> System DSN
>
> Unlike a User DSN, a System DSN is not user-specific. A System DSN is
>   stored locally and is not dedicated to a particular user. Any user who
>   logs on to a computer that has permission to access the data source
>   can use a System DSN. Some programs, such as Microsoft SQL Server or
>   Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS), require a System DSN.
>   This DSN must be created on the server where the program is located.
>
> System DSNs are stored in the Windows registry under the following
>   key:
>
> ```
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Odbc\Odbc.ini\Odbc Data sources
> ```

Note that you would need to ensure everyone operating in support was familiar with this, as now problem reports for a given DSN do not resolve to a single database instance.

Comment: the obvious things are sometimes the least visible :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think with SQL Server you can define a default database for each login.  If you do that and leave the database name out of the DSN you should always connect to that users default database.